# Where are the admin notifications stored?

Tags: wp-admin, notifications

I'm looking to add some custom functionality to the admin side and I want to change the way the admin notifications work. Where are the admin notifications stored? And when a user dismisses one, where is that being recorded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where are the admin notifications stored?

**They aren't.** Admin notices have no storage unless you implement it yourself for your plugin/theme.

WordPress provides hooks and styling for displaying admin notices, but that's it. It might provide styling for dismissible admin notices but it provides no storage or registration mechanisms for persistence.

> And when a user dismisses one, where is that being recorded?

**It isn't**, native WP admin notices don't provide this, it's implemented by the plugin/theme author. They might store this in a cookie, local storage, user meta, etc, you would need to ask each plugin/theme vendor individually. There is currently no general mechanism.

---

As an aside, there is a feature plugin for creating a notification centre in core, but at the time of writing it has not been merged, and its status is uncertain. You should give it a look.

Comment: By any chance do you know where or how the system keeps track of when an admin user dismisses a WooCommerce notice?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind I was able to trace back what I was looking for. Thanks for the info!